# custom callback on jquery event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working with jquery and jstree

I have an event that triggers every time my tree changes:

```js
$tree.jstree()
    .on("changed.jstree",  function(event, target) {
        //manipulate data
    });
```

It works perfect. I can access "this" (the tree), and also event and target. But, I am trying to define a custom callback. I tried something like this:

```
window.customCallback = (function(event, target) {
    //manipulate data
    //$(this).foo() manipulates the tree
    //event.type to access the event type
    //target.node to access the node
}(this));
```

So I can use:

```js
$tree.jstree()
    .on("changed.jstree",  customCallback(event, target));
```

But it doesn't work. Could somebody help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $tree.jstree().on("changed.jstree", customCallback(event, target));

What you're *doing* is setting the **result** of `customCallback` as callback handler.

What you *want to do* is set the function itself as callback handler:

```
var customCallback = function(event, target) {
// ...
};

$tree.jstree().on("changed.jstree", customCallback);
```

Notice the "missing" brackets - because brackets would invoke the function and we don't want that.

The parameters will be passed to the handler automatically.